# Adding object into a list c# -windows phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8

I need to have 2 lists (List A and List B), the data source for both the list is a JSON array object, List A contains all the records from JSON response and List B contains a subset of it, based on the status type of the object. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Result
{
    public int request_id { get; set; }
    public string createdTime { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }

}
```

I m parsing it using JSON.NET and populating List A

```
 var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 RootObject rootoject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseString)[0];
        ListBox1.ItemsSource = rootoject.result;
```

Im querying list of records based on status here

```
HashSet<Result> sample = new HashSet<Result>(rootoject.result.Where(item
            => item.status == "approved"));
 List<RootObject> approvedlist = new List<RootObject>();

       **approvedlist.Add(sample); Getting error here cannot convert from hashset to Rootobject**
```

I tried

```
 RootObject sample=new HashSet<Result>(rootoject.result.Where(item
            => item.status == "approved"));
```

This also gives me error.

Comment: Well yes - you're trying to add a `HashSet<Result>` to a `List<RootObject>` - what do you *expect* that to do?

Comment: RootObject sample=new HashSet<Result>(rootoject.result.Where(item
            => item.status == "approved")); this leaves me with an error.. I dunno how to get this working..

Comment: You cannot add the HashSet of Result to RootObject List, but you can add if both are of type Result

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi: Well again, how would you *expect* that to work? A `HashSet<Result>` simply *isn't* a `RootObject`, is it?

Comment: Yeah i know.. I have issue with type conversion.. I was not able to get the queries result in rootobject type..I have mentioned that in the last line of code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ( I don't have a compiler near by)

```
var  sampleList = new HashSet<Result>(rootoject.result.Where(item
            => item.status == "approved")).ToList();
var sampleRootObject = new RootObject();
sampleRootObject.result = sampleList; // The setter needs to be made public
approvedList.Add( sampleRootObject);
```

Comment: Wen I use your code I dont get any errors but while binding to the list I dont get the values.Thanks for your help !!

Comment: ListBox2.ItemsSource = sampleRootObject.result; Now i get the values in List box.. before i was using ListBox2.ItemsSource=approvedList.. @philip ngan thanks again!!